# Which of these is correct? I or me?

Tags: phrases, verbs, sentence, formality, writing

“Do you want to come with Lucy and I?”

“Do you want to come with Lucy and me?”

When do we say “I” instead of “me” and “me” instead of “I”?

Thank you

Comment: A simple trick is to remove 'Lucy and' - would you say "Do you want to come with I?", or "Do you want to come with me?"

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! It’s been very helpful ✨

Comment: And another example, "Jane and I/me would like to go to the store".

Comment: In this case, we use “I” since we have a conjugated verb following the pronouns? “I would like to go to the store” not “me would like to go to the store?”

Comment: Yes that's correct!

Comment: Yayyy!  Thank you very much for the help you provided! I am not a native speaker, but I learn English everyday so I can get better at it! ✨

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to come with Lucy and me?

because Lucy and me are the object(s) of the sentence.